# Why I Can't mine using my private network?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

Mist Version: `0.10.0`
OS & Version: windows/64
Node version: `geth 8.11.1`

Screen shot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqGsO.jpg

I've created a private network all fine but when I attache and miner.start(1); the kh/s show in Mist but I keep waiting and no ether got mine not a single one!!!

https://codeshare.io/GqxZ3Z
this is the code of the first command line where I start geth

https://codeshare.io/2pgZYX
this is the second terminal where I start mining command

Genisis file:

```
{ "coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001", 
  "difficulty" : "0x20000", 
 "extraData" : "", 
 "gasLimit" : "0x8000000", 
 "nonce" : "0x0000000000000042", 
 "mixhash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
 "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
 "timestamp" : "0x00", "alloc": {}, "config": { "chainId": 15, "homesteadBlock": 0, "eip155Block": 0, "eip158Block": 0 } }
```

thanks guys

Comment: Can you edit your question to add your genesis file? Are you sure you are mining in a private network and not mainnet? Can you try launching `geth` with more logs enabled with `--verbosity 4`?

Comment: Genisis got added, yes I'm pretty sure, don't know how to do that

Comment: Your difficulty is too high I'd start with `0x200` or lower. If you modify your genesis you have to start again your blockchain to delete all previous data. To discard an ipc issue type your command `mine.start(1)` in the console of same instance.

Comment: I will start over with 0x200 difficulty so i have to delete all files data and start again, right?

Comment: I've deleted the 2 files inside chaindata which are "geth" & "keystore" then make difficulty 0x200 and start a new private chain using init, and start geth, open mist and attach all fine but when start.miner i get this error of coinbase: https://imgur.com/a/0iUskES

Comment: You need an account in order to mine, create an account with `personal.newAccount("PASSWORD")`, then it should start to mine (the first time it will have to create the DAG it should take several minutes).

Comment: Should I use the console or just after starting geth to create the account?

Comment: You can type the `personal.newAccount` command in the same instance without restarting.

Comment: Im getting this error 'personal.newAccount' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: When I do geth account new and they ask me to assign a password I can't type anymore, plz see screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/iF5nEhx

Comment: You can type the command in the geth console `personal.newAccount("PASSWORD")` replacing PASSWORD for something that you can remember.

Comment: Im getting this error 'personal.newAccount' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: You have to type that in the geth's console, not in the cmd's console.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have an error about the IPC from your geth running command. (bottom left in red)

Comment: What will cause the error? The remixx eth address is correct what will be the problem?

Comment: Can you add your geth command line to your post please?

Comment: Any thoughts yet about the error?

Comment: Not 100% sure about but the `--mine` option is not needed to run a private miner? https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum#running-a-private-miner

Comment: Honestly I don't know